# What Perforce (p4) command lists the files in a given changelist?

Tags: version-control, perforce, configuration-management

What Perforce `p4` command lists the files changed in a given changelist?  Note that I want only the names of the files that have changed and not the content differences.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
p4 describe -s <changelist>
```

Example output:

```
p4 describe -s 42

Change 42 by someUser@someClient on 2010/08/17 18:43:35

        updated foo.txt

Affected files ...

... //foo.txt#2 edit
```

Answer (score 2):

See the documentation for [`describe`](http://www.perforce.com/perforce/doc.082/manuals/p4guide/08_scripting.html#1040479). You probably want:

```
p4 describe changenum
```

But you may also find these useful:

To show the files in a pending changelist:

```
p4 opened -c changenum
```

To suppress the diffs in `p4 describe`:

```
p4 describe -s changenum
```